# Typescript type predicate results in never

Tags: typescript, predicate, instanceof

The following typescript snippet reproduce the (compiler) issue in strict mode, the compiled code runs fine:

```js
class ClassX
{
    constructor(public label: string) {}
}

class ClassA extends ClassX
{
    constructor() { super('A'); }
}

class ClassB extends ClassX
{
    constructor() { super('B'); }
}

type TClass = ClassA | ClassB;

class Wrapper<T extends TClass>
{
    constructor(public source: TClass)
    {
        if(Wrapper.IsB(this)) console.log(this.source.label);

        // Works normally:
        // if(source instanceof ClassA) this.Log();
        // else if(source instanceof ClassB) this.Log();

        if(Wrapper.IsA(this)) console.log(this.source.label);
        // this results in 'never', would emit error TS2339 without the type guard
        else if(Wrapper.IsB(this)) console.log((this as Wrapper<ClassB>).source.label);
    }

    public static IsA(wrapper: Wrapper<TClass>): wrapper is Wrapper<ClassA>
    {
        return wrapper.source instanceof ClassA;
    }

    public static IsB(wrapper: Wrapper<TClass>): wrapper is Wrapper<ClassB>
    {
        return wrapper.source instanceof ClassB;
    }
}

console.log('ClassA');
new Wrapper(new ClassA()); // logs 'A'

console.log('\nClassB');
new Wrapper(new ClassB()); // logs 'BB'
```

I'm suspecting the compiler is narrowing down to the common base type `ClassX`, however I'm not testing against the base class! Doesn't subclasses have precedence over the base as far as `instanceof` is concerned?

What am I missing?

Comment: It compiles fine on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Comment: @zerkms It does,edited my question to reflect that it emits TS2339 (prop not found) when in strict mode.

Comment: It compiles fine on play with strict mode (which is by default there, but check the `Config` tab)

Comment: It compiles without errors or warnings on play. What TS version do you run?

Comment: Okay, I see - you meant `else if(Wrapper.IsB(this)) console.log(this.source.label);` this code does not compile?

Comment: @zerkms It doesn't, not without the type guard. Tested with 3.7.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To a first approximation, TypeScript's type system is [structural](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing), not [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system).  That means type `A` and type `B` are considered to be the same type in TypeScript if and only they have the same *structure*, not if they have the same *name* (or, more accurately,  declaration).  That also means type `A` and type `B` are considered to be *different* types if and only if they have *different* structures, not just if they have different names (or declarations).

In the code from your example, `ClassA` and `ClassB` have the same structure, so the compiler considers them the same type.  If a type guard on `x is ClassA` returns `false`, then the compiler considers that `x` is not `ClassA`, and therefore it is also not `ClassB`.  This is obviously not your intent; you want `ClassA` and `ClassB` to be considered different types.  An easy way to fix this is to [add a `private` property to each class](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#when-and-why-are-classes-nominal), or any two different properties, like this:

```
class ClassA extends ClassX {
    readonly name = "A"; // type name is string literal "A"
    constructor() { super('A'); }
}

class ClassB extends ClassX {
    readonly name = "B"; // type name is string literal "B"
    constructor() { super('B'); }
}
```

That gives `ClassA` a `name` property of the [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) type `"A"`, and `ClassB` a `name` of the string literal type `"B"`.  The compiler sees them as distinct now, and all is well, right?

---

Wrong!  The problem persists, because of the same issue with `Wrapper<T>`.  In this case, your `Wrapper<T>` class [does not depend structurally on `T`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--).  The compiler sees no difference between `Wrapper<ClassA>` and `Wrapper<ClassB>` even when `ClassA` and `ClassB` are different.  You can tell this because `T` shows up inside the class name and nowhere in the definition.  And since the type system isn't nominal, it doesn't matter that the *name* `Wrapper<ClassA>` is different from `Wrapper<ClassB>`.  They're the same type.

I'm assuming maybe you wanted the constructor parameter to be `public source: T` instead of `public source: TClass`, like this:

```
constructor(public source: T) { ... }
```

That would have the effect of `Wrapper<T>` having a `source` property of type `T`, and therefore `Wrapper<ClassA>` and `Wrapper<ClassB>` would be distinct, since `source.name` would be different types.

And *now* `this` doesn't get reduced to `never` after you guard against `Wrapper<ClassA>` and `Wrapper<ClassB>` separately:

```
constructor(public source: T) {
    if (Wrapper.IsA(this)) console.log(this.source.label);
    else if (Wrapper.IsB(this)) console.log((this).source.label); // okay
}
```

Okay, hope that helps give you some ideas.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-TB1twU4QpglXKPx5J8FwvKAAdAgp0vDBHzvRNaQfG9dxfAI33-T9mjOIA)

Comment: I was expecting to @jcalz to answer this :)

Comment: @jcalz Amazing answer! I was trying to analyse the issue thinking in runtime features (instanceof), instead of investigating static checking (Oh man!). Thanks for highlighting the nominal/structural type systems.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I added "declaration" in there, thanks.

Comment: @jcalz  much appreciated :)